# ssh session get disconnected very frequently through a unknown scanner ip

Tags: ssh, security

I have very problem with ssh connection
all different type of disconnection error from 1 second to more but very frequently that does not allow me to work

-change sshd config DONE

-different server DONE

-different client DONE

-password and/or rsa key DONE

-iptables and hosts deny/allow DONE

-cannot afford to change router and ISP as one post suggest big differences

I checked journalctl and find something interest

```
sshd[954]: Connection closed by 45.79.181.223 port 4704 [preauth]
```

some foreign scanner with that ip ( and other scanner ips ) get to close my connection!? how is it possible to be done with rsa key I used!?

I cannot set an static ip to be allowed for ssh! but really how some random ip could close my rsa key protected session?

Found new error from LogLevel DEBUG3

```
debug3: recv - from CB ERROR:10060, io:00000133F9C50760 debug3: send packet: type 1 debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:00000133F9C50760
```

Found this also

When Firebird on Windows has a problem with the network subsystem an unknown Win32 error comes back with a numer (like e.g. 10060). The number is a Winsock error number. This is a list of all Winsock error numbers so you can look up the meaning of the number:

http://www.destructor.de/firebird/winsockerrors.htm

Comment: You will find various solutions the this problem in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102502/meaning-of-connection-closed-by-xxx-preauth-in-sshd-logs). Try the answers there one after the other, and let me know if one worked for you, and I will put up an answer.

Comment: no one of them work! some make it better for some minutes maybe (placebo!) and again get discconected so fast especially if open some file with nano and try to change (maybe this also placebo!)

Comment: Your problem is then different.

Comment: The log message is a fact of being on the internet. Ignore it. It is entirely unrelated to whatever problems you may be facing. Please describe your problems in greater detail. Please provide details on what exactly you did to try and fix it.

Comment: try to connect to digitalocean droplet and amazon ec2 free tier micro through password and rsa key, openssh powershell window 10, putty and wsl ubuntu. enable and disable both firewall of windows and server, check host deny allow and nothing there in fail2ba, no blocking in iptables, change rsa key to only user can read in windows, but randomly get disconnected while i am type and working in ssh session. what elase detail i can provide? the error in normal mode and debug3 mode and journalctl also provided. I really dont know what to do more.

Comment: Do you mean like you are experiencing the same problem with multiple different server?

Comment: Yes I mean I think the problem is not the server at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.
I fix it totally by just disable firewall of router. It is now very reliable for hours without problems.

```
Firewall : Disabled
        
(WARNING: If you enabled Firewall, the modem can block such attack:Denial of Service, SYN Flooding, Ping of Death, TearDrop...etc)
```